# Принципы чистого кода в ООП Python

Tags: python, ооп

```
class b:
    def temp(self):
        print('a')


class a(b):
    def main(self):
        #-----
        # Правильна ли запись self.temp()
        #----- 
        self.temp()
        print('b')
```

При вызове функции в классе обязательно должна выполняться вместе с этим другая функция класса. По принципу чистого когда, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Наверное, через декораторы

Comment: По принципу чистого кода надо сперва определиться, какую задачу вообще решаем. Когда какая-то там функция «обязательно должна выполниться» — это слишком абстрактно и непонятно зачем надо; без конкретной задачи вести речи о чистом коде — весьма сомнительная затея, ибо есть риск попасть в [ошибку XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710)

Comment: про декораторы можно точнее? Ведь писать декоратор под одну функцию не имеет смыслы

Answer (score 1):

да, можно и так:

```
class B:
    def temp(self):
        print('\na')


class A(B):
    def main(self):
        #-----
        # Правильна ли запись self.temp()
        #----- 
        self.temp()
        print('b')
        
a = A()
a.main() 
a.temp()
```

---

update

> можете показать еще варианты

я бы написал так:

```
class B:
    def temp(self):
        print('\na')


class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.main()
        
    def main(self):
        self.temp()
        print('b')
        
a = A()
```

Comment: Это то понятно можно и в конструктор запихнуть тут суть в другом

Comment: @Rolles пожалуйста, о сути поподробнее. Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: вопрос в том на сколько это правильно в написании есть ли другие способы это реализовать. А то голый висящий вызов функции смущает

Comment: @Rolles написать можно по-разному, у вас написан рабочий вариант.

Comment: понятно что рабочий, можете показать еще варианты ?

Comment: @Rolles вопрос не в том как написать, а в том какой порядок действий вам нужно получить при создании экземпляра класса.  я добавил другой вариант

Comment: `super(A, self).__init__()` - это то же самое, что и `super().__init__()`?

Comment: @Rolles да,  это то же самое

Answer (score 0):

```
class B:
    def temp(self):
        print('\na')


class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.main()
        
    def main(self):
        self.temp()
        print('b')
        
a = A()
```

> super(A, self).**init**()
> используется в python2

```
class b:
    def temp(self):
        print('a')


class a(b):
    def main(self):
        super().temp()
        print('b')
```

> Проще будет такая запись